# How to find the time is fall between two times?

Tags: php, time

I am having two times in database.
`Starting Time 07:00`  and 
`Ending Time 07:25` and
 If your chooses the starting time from my application 07:10 and End time is 07:35 I need to inform the time is not available for booking.
How can I check this `07:10 and 07:35` fall between `07:00 and 07:25` using PHP?Thanks in advance?

Update:
They May Give like this also 
`06:50 to 07:15`.At that time also I need to find this time falls between the previous times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the times into number of minutes since the start of the day which will make the comparison easier.

```
07:00 = 07 * 60 + 00 = 420 call this $Start
```

and

```
07:25 = 07 * 60 + 25 = 445 call this $End
```

Similarly convert your user input `hh:mm` to min as above and call them `$userStart` and `$userEnd`. Now all you need to do is:

```
if($userStart >= $Start && $userEnd <= $End) {
  // valid
}
```

Comment: I simply use the strtotime function and use the code like above for condition checking.I got the result.Thanks.